# JavaScript variable from PHP dynamic dropdown in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I can get this popup to return the proper value when I type the actual `var` choice in to the url that exists in the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = $.get("logbookincludes/sqftpoles.php?choice=Front Range", function(data) {
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
</script>
```

I want the variable to be set by the actual dropdown selector `id`. I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

```
var data = $.get("logbookincludes/sqftpoles.php?choice=" +    $("#item36_select_1").val());
```

Here's the server side php to fill the selector dropdown.

**zones.php**

```
 <?php
  include("dbinfo.php");

$query = "SELECT zonename FROM zone";

$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option>" . $row{'zonename'} . "</option>";
}
    ?>
```

Here's the dropdown code.

```
Zone
 <select name="zone" id="item36_select_1" required data-hint="">
        <option id="item36_0_option" selected value="Front Range">
          Front Range
        </option>
      <? include('logbookincludes/zones.php');?>
      </select>
```

Here's the **sqftpoles.php**

```
   <?php
   include("dbinfo.php");

$choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);

$query = "SELECT sqftpoles FROM zone WHERE zonename = '$choice'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

    $result2=mysql_query($query2);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo  $row{'sqftpoles'};
}   
   ?>
```

Comment: Can you show the server side code

Comment: I just edited my post to include the server side php and the dropdown code. Makedon's reply returned an empty popup box. I'm only using it for testing.

Comment: Your sqftpoles.php file doesn't look like it's syntactically correct.

Comment: The sqftpoles.php returns the proper value in the popup in my original post when I type the actual variable into the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is example code correct:

```
$.get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/' + 'javascript', function(data){
    alert(data);
})
```

Here's the code you need. Javascript is a client language

```
$.get('logbookincludes/sqftpoles.php?choice=' + $("#item36_select_1").val(), function(data){
    alert(data);
});



function updatesub(){
  $.get('logbookincludes/sqftpoles.php?choice=' + $("#item36_select_1").val(), function(data){
   var u = $('#item44_number_1').val()-0,
       q = $('#sqftofzone').val()-0,
       n = data-0;
   $('#item49_number_1').val(u*q*n);
   alert(data);
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. Now I get an empty Popup.

Comment: Is it correct url logbookincludes/sqftpoles.php?choice=" + $("#item36_select_1").val() ?

Comment: You have to configure your Web server (or 127.0.0.1)? What is the address you type into your browser to see what gives your php code?

Comment: Yes,this works. $.get("logbookincludes/sqftpoles.php?choice=Front Range", function(data) {
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);  Front Range is in the database. I just can't get it to pick it up from the selector. Which shows the proper value. I put it in as the default value for testing.

Comment: Unsure of your question but here's the url to see the value show from direct url typing. http://ericrohloff.com/pesticide/logbookincludes/sqftpoles.php?choice=Front%20Range

Comment: Just add `http://ericrohloff.com/pesticide` to the url.    (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15449433/450555)

Comment: Same results typing the front part of the url. The front part isn't the problem. It's the **+ $("#item36_select_1").val()** that's not being set.

Comment: `<select name="zone" id="item36_select_1" required data-hint="">
        <option id="item36_0_option" selected value="Front Range">
          Front Range
        </option>
</select>`       //  **$("#item36_select_1").val()** returns the 'Front Range' for this code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15449433/450555 I rewrote your function - now it is working properly.

Comment: Thank You very much. Works spot on. I understand some of the short hand code you wrote but will study and read more to educate myself. Your time is greatly appreciated. I was able to drop the absolute url in the final resolution.;)